# Add parent object to List<? extends Parent> - Java

Tags: java, generic-collections

I am trying to put a subclass object into a List but I am unable to do so because of the compiler error mentioned as a comment. Can someone point out what is the correct way to do this in Java?

```
public class Animal { }

class Util {

    private Map<Class<? extends Animal>, List<? extends Animal>> animalListMap;

    public void registerAnimal(Class<? extends Animal> animalClass, Animal animalObject) {

        if (animalListMap.containsKey(animalClass)) {
            //Append to the existing List
            List<? extends Animal> animalList = animalListMap.get(animalObject);
            animalList.add(animalObject); //COMPILE ERROR- The method add(capture#3-of ? extends Animal) in the type List<capture#3-of ? extends Animal> is not applicable for the arguments (Animal)
        } else {
            // and the new entry
            List<Animal> vos = new ArrayList<Animal>();
            vos.add(animalObject);
            animalListMap.put(animalClass, vos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, `animalListMap.get(animalObject)` should be `animalListMap.get(animalClass)`.

Comment: You are passing instance Object, in the place of Class object

Comment: animalListMap.get(animalObject); should be animalListMap.get(animalClass);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add anything to a `List<? extends Animal>`, ever. `List<? extends Animal>` means "a list of I-don't-know-what-but-something-that-extends-Animal", which could be a `List<Animal>` or a `List<Cat>`.

If you could, this code would compile:

```
List dogs = new ArrayList();
List animals = dogs;
animals.add(new Cat());
Dog dog = dogs.get(0);
```

You can, however, change `List<? extends Animal>` to `List<Animal>` which seems to be what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

You declare

```
List<? extends Animal> animalList = animalListMap.get(animalObject);
```

The `? extends Animal` is a wildcard bounded by the `Animal` class. So `animalListMap.get(animalObject);` could return a `List<Donkey>`, `List<Mouse>`, `List<Pikachu>`, assuming `Donkey`, `Mouse`, and `Pikachu` were all sub classes of `Animal`. However, with the wildcard, you are telling the compiler that you don't care what the actual type is as long as it is a sub type of `Animal`.

Since you don't know what it is, you can't actually add anything (except `null`) to it. If what you got back was a `List<Pikachu>`, but `animalObject` was actually referencing a `Donkey` object, you would have problems down the line. That's why the compiler won't let this code compile.

If you have a `List<Animal>`, then you can add any object that has the type or parent type `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `animalList` is a list of something that extends animal, but may not be concretely animal.  In other words it may be restricted to some subtype of animal, for instance you could have a list of Lion, Tiger or Bear (oh my!).

As well, your code is prone to weirdness, consider the following calling code example:

```
myUtil.registerAnimal(Zebra.class, new Tiger());
```

Comment: "Because animalList is a list of something that extends animal, but may not be animal." incorrecto. Of course they are all animals, but there may be further restriction that it has to be a certain type of animal as your example demonstrates.

Comment: @RAY clarified that bit

Comment: To address the weirdness, I suggest genericize the method:

Comment: public <A extends Animal> void registerAnimal(Class<A> animalClass, A animalObject)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this declaration

```
private Map<Class<? extends Animal>, List<? extends Animal>> animalListMap;
```

if you intend to add Animals to the List.

`List<? extends Animal>>` instructs the complier not to allow to add anything but null to that List.